# Set a column in Pandas based on if another column contains a name from a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have been struggling with this one for a bit so I figured it was time to ask.

I have a list of names:

```
names = ["john", "sally", "tom"]
```

I have a df and one of the columns is `action`.
`action` has many different things, e.g.:

- "Went for a walk with tom"
- "Took sally to the store"
- ...

I want to make a new column called `partner` and set that to the name that is in `action`.
I already have the column set and it is filled for some logs but not all.

I tried:

```
for name in names:
    df['partner'] =  np.where(df.action.str.contains(name), name, df['partner'] )
```

But I get this error:

> TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern

Am I going about this the right way? Is there a better way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: To make a sample of my df you could use:

```
names = ["john", "sally", "tom"]
d = {'name': ['mark','rick','mark','jon', 'lenny'], 'action': ['Went for a walk with tom', 'Took sally to the store', 'Went for a walk with john', 'Went racing with tom and lost', 'Took john to the store'],
    'partner': ['tom', '', 'john', '', 'john']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

the list 'names' has all the possible names that could be in the string, so I figured the easiest was to find which name was in the string and set that to the partners column.

Here is the full error i get:

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-ed79b0ff06a7> in <module>()
     11 
     12 for partner in partners:
---> 13     EscrowLogs.loc[EscrowLogs.action.str.contains(partner), 'partner'] = partner
     14 
     15 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py in contains(self, pat, case, flags, na, regex)
   2415     def contains(self, pat, case=True, flags=0, na=np.nan, regex=True):
   2416         result = str_contains(self._data, pat, case=case, flags=flags, na=na,
-> 2417                               regex=regex)
   2418         return self._wrap_result(result)
   2419 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py in str_contains(arr, pat, case, flags, na, regex)
    385             flags |= re.IGNORECASE
    386 
--> 387         regex = re.compile(pat, flags=flags)
    388 
    389         if regex.groups > 0:

~\Anaconda3\lib\re.py in compile(pattern, flags)
    232 def compile(pattern, flags=0):
    233     "Compile a regular expression pattern, returning a Pattern object."
--> 234     return _compile(pattern, flags)
    235 
    236 def purge():

~\Anaconda3\lib\re.py in _compile(pattern, flags)
    283         return pattern
    284     if not sre_compile.isstring(pattern):
--> 285         raise TypeError("first argument must be string or compiled pattern")
    286     p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
    287     if not (flags & DEBUG):

TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of your data formatted as a pandas dataframe? Thanks.

Comment: The `.str.contains` method is not vectorized so you'll want to think carefully about your iterations here

Comment: Much as I hate to say it; this might be a case for `apply` and some regex to get the matches against a dict. I'm just not the person to build that as an answer. But, you at least only take a single pass at the df rows

Comment: To be fair, this depends on the size of the data. My hunch is that it may be fairly small and applying regex would be overkill.

Comment: @k_n_c I can already see the time complexity blow up on this if your hunch is wrong. It's not easy to break the sentences down and I suspect it touches on many different methods

Comment: @roganjosh You're 100% right; they should certainly avoid that method if the data is not in fact small. RiotF, care to share how many rows you're handling?

Comment: So each `action` is guaranteed to contain only one `name`?

Comment: It could be a couple of thousand rows. And yes, there would only be one of each name.

Comment: Can you add the full error message to your post?  And what is currently in the `partner` column?  Your code returns a different error if that column does not exist when you run the for-loop.

Comment: Can you try adding `regex=False` as an argument: `str.contains(name, regex=False)`

Comment: Some of the rows have the partner column set already, others do not.

Comment: I updated the sample and the full error

Comment: With the RegEx = False added i get the error of:
KeyError: '[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan] not in index'

Comment: I deleted a few nans so it would fit.

Comment: The `TypeError` is purely a regex compile error (`str.contains()` uses Python's `re` module under the hood, and the error is coming from that module), which suggests that there is a value in your data regex is not able to handle.  Similarly, the `KeyError` suggests a similar problem. Normally, you would try to write a try-except block to catch the row/column/cell where the problem occurs (no problems happen with the sample data and code you provided). If you can't resolve the problem, I can help with try-except later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on my comment, you could write a function to iterate over rows of your dataframe and catch values that produce an error/exception.

For example, you could use this function that returns a null value if the action field could not be parsed:

```
names = ["john", "sally", "tom"]

def get_partner(p, a):
    # if row already contains partner value, leave as is
    if p:
        return p
    # otherwise, extract partner name from the action column
    else:
        try:
            for name in names:
                if name in a:
                    return name
        # for any problematic action strings, return null value
        # (can be replaced with some other string that you can later check)
        except:
            return None
```

You could also use this function that does not require looping over names. It splits each sentence into a list of words and removes all words that are not found in the list of names, leaving you with just the name value.  If there is more than one name, it uses a comma delimiter to separate them.

```
names = ["john", "sally", "tom"]

def get_partner(p, a):
    # if row already contains partner value, leave as is
    if p:
        return p
    # otherwise, extract partner name(s) from the action column
    else:
        try:
            return ",".join([i for i in a.split() if i in names])
        # for any problematic action strings, return null value
        # (can be replaced with some other string that you can later check)
        except:
            return None
```

You would then use `.apply()` to run the function on your dataframe:

```
df['partner'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_partner(x['partner'], x['action']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would need a verifiable sample of your data to be sure, but using boolean indexing should work:

```
for name in names:
     df.loc[df.action.str.contains(name), 'partner'] = name
```

Comment: I got the same error with this. I will try and update with a sample of my df.